# Dynamic class method invocation in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way to dynamically invoke a method in the same class for PHP? I don't have the syntax right, but I'm looking to do something similar to this:

```
$this->{$methodName}($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

Comment: Was it the original question ? I was looking for invoking a method dynamically and I found this question. It<s the same syntax given by andy.gurin and I don't see a link that shows the update on the question. Anyway... Thanks to have asked and thanks to the contributers :-)

Comment: @Luc - It was the original question. It turns out that I did have the syntax right when I asked, but something else was wrong with my code, so it didn't work.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate (not sure which one would be a better target...) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954168/how-to-use-class-methods-as-callbacks

Answer (score 209, accepted):

There is more than one way to do that:

```
$this->{$methodName}($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
$this->$methodName($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
call_user_func_array(array($this, $methodName), array($arg1, $arg2, $arg3));
```

You may even use the reflection api http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflection.php

Comment: I guess maybe I did have the syntax right, so something else is wrong with my code as it's not quite functioning correctly. Hmm...

Comment: A word to the weary, if your methods are being called on objects and tested with PHPUnit, `call_user_func_array` is the one for you.

Comment: You my friend, just saved my day! I was calling `call_user_func_array($this->$name, ...)` and wondered why it wouldn't work!

Comment: Thanks ,this work for me.
$this->$methodName($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Overloading in PHP:
[Overloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

```
class Test {

    private $name;

    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        echo 'Method Name:' . $name . ' Arguments:' . implode(',', $arguments);
        //do a get
        if (preg_match('/^get_(.+)/', $name, $matches)) {
            $var_name = $matches[1];
            return $this->$var_name ? $this->$var_name : $arguments[0];
        }
        //do a set
        if (preg_match('/^set_(.+)/', $name, $matches)) {
            $var_name = $matches[1];
            $this->$var_name = $arguments[0];
        }
    }
}

$obj = new Test();
$obj->set_name('Any String'); //Echo:Method Name: set_name Arguments:Any String
echo $obj->get_name();//Echo:Method Name: get_name Arguments:
                      //return: Any String
```

Answer (score 13):

Just omit the braces:

```
$this->$methodName($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `call_user_func()` and `call_user_func_array()`

Answer (score 4):

If you're working within a class in PHP, then I would recommend using the overloaded __call function in PHP5. You can find the reference [here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php).

Basically __call does for dynamic functions what __set and __get do for variables in OO PHP5.

Answer (score 2):

In my case.

```
$response = $client->{$this->requestFunc}($this->requestMsg);
```

Using PHP SOAP.

Comment: I am not sure but be careful about security issue

Answer (score 2):

You can store a method in a single variable using a closure:

```
class test{        

    function echo_this($text){
        echo $text;
    }

    function get_method($method){
        $object = $this;
        return function() use($object, $method){
            $args = func_get_args();
            return call_user_func_array(array($object, $method), $args);           
        };
    }
}

$test = new test();
$echo = $test->get_method('echo_this');
$echo('Hello');  //Output is "Hello"
```

EDIT: I've edited the code and now it's compatible with PHP 5.3. Another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27149017/428640)

Answer (score 1):

Still valid after all these years! Make sure you trim `$methodName` if it is user defined content. I could not get `$this->$methodName` to work until I noticed it had a leading space.

Comment: If it's user defined content make sure you do much more than just trim the name! Such as... security check it! ;)

Comment: Somewhere on the internet, I detailed how to convert user entered utf8 into windows-safe characters. QuickBooks ran me through that wringer -- and why QB is no longer part of how I complete sales...

Comment: Are you really allowing client to specify an input, that call dynamically some methods ?! I have no words

Comment: Obviously validated and checked that the class actually contains such a named method.  There are many ways to check the value.  It beats a lengthy switch statement.