# PHP: array('function' => 'theme_select_as_checkboxes')

Tags: php

what does this construct mean in PHP ? It is storing a variable called "function" with his String value in an array ?

```
array('function' => 'theme_select_as_checkboxes')
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like declaring an [associative array](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). With sucha an array, you can retrieve the content of the array this way :

```
$myArray = array('function' => 'theme_select_as_checkboxes');
echo $myArray['function']; // Prints 'theme_select_as_checkboxes
```

No magic in here ! ;)

Answer (score 4):

its just an associative array and unless some context is given, doesnt mean anything special!

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be a function/method name that can be called at a later time. Other than the data, it looks to be just a standard array.

You may be interested in this question as well: [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable).

Answer (score 0):

this is not a special structure. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art31316.asp