# php call standard function by string

Tags: php

I need to call a PHP standard function from a string

Example:

```
$param = "parameter";
$functionname = "createimagefromjpg";
//call the function (with a parameter)
```

Anyone has an idea how I can do this?
It can't be done with `call_user_func()` because it is a standard function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 5):

```
$functionname($param);
```

Answer (score -1):

Correction, ok I thought this would work:

```
$$functionname($param);
```

but it does not.... the example with one dollar sign works for functions.  Nice.

Comment: $$name is to find a variable whose name is stored in `name`, so if you had `$foo = "bar"; $bar = "baz";` and you wanted to call `baz()`, you could do `$bar()` or `$$foo()`