# explode string and call dynamic function

Tags: php, function, dynamic, explode

I have a string that is formatted like this:

```
function1!!param1||ignore!!param2&&function2!!param1||ignore!!param2||ignore!!param3
```

The number of functions it has is unlimited (they are split with &&)

a basic function call that would be generated from the string above is:

```
function1($param1,$param2);
```

and the second one:

```
function2($param1,$param2,$param3);
```

the number of params is unlimited. (they aren't called function and param that is only an example)

Happy to answer any questions!! I already tried exploding by && and then !! but I can't quite figure out how to call a dynamic function with dynamic params.

Solution for 5.2:

```
function function1( $a1, $a2 ) {
    echo $a1 . $a2;
}

function function2( $a1, $a2, $a3 ) {
    echo " ".$a1 . $a2 . $a3;
}
function explodemap($val) {
        $explode = explode( "!!", $val );
        return $explode[1];
}
$functions = explode( "&&", 'function1!!param1||ignore!!param2&&function2!!param1||ignore!!param2||ignore!!param3' );

foreach( $functions as $function ) {
    $split = explode( "||", $function );
    $weird_excalmation_split = explode("!!", $split[0] );
    $params = array_slice( $split, 1 );

    $params = array_map( "explodemap", $params );

    $fn_name = $weird_excalmation_split[0];
    array_unshift( $params, $weird_excalmation_split[1]  );

    call_user_func_array( $fn_name, $params );
}
```

Comment: You probably don't need me to tell you this is a really bad pattern, but perhaps you've inherited it. You don't say what `ignore` does...

Comment: Have a look at [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which you obviously will have to apply more than once and then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable) to see how to call a function's name stored in a string.

Comment: @Lorof - no I didn't downvote you. It was done when I got here. Anonymous downvotes suck.

Comment: If you receive this data from an Android application that means your data is not secure and could easily be changed by a potential hacker. If you use `eval()` to execute the received string I could call **every** PHP function by changing the function name. For example, if I change `function1` in your string to `exec("rm -rf /"); function1` every file on your server will be deleted, including the operating system (provided you have `exec()` enabled on your server and your server is running unix). But you can see how dangerous `eval()` is, so never use it!

Comment: @Lorof: No problem. :) It is safer, but still not safe enough. Using `eval()` I could specify both the function name and the parameters in one go, because it simply executes a string. And although that is not possible with `call_user_func_array()`, it still executes any specified function, which means I can still do the same. If I would change your string to `exec!!rm -rf /` you would still have a problem. Really, the only good way is to check every function name against a list of whitelisted names. Should I add an answer below with some example code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
function function1( $a1, $a2 ) {
    echo $a1 . $a2;
}

function function2( $a1, $a2, $a3 ) {
    echo $a1 . $a2 . $a3;
}

$functions = explode( "&&", 'function1!!param1||ignore!!param2&&function2!!param1||ignore!!param2||ignore!!param3' );

foreach( $functions as $function ) {
    $split = explode( "||", $function );
    $weird_excalmation_split = explode("!!", $split[0] );
    $params = array_slice( $split, 1 );

    $params = array_map( function($val) {
        return explode( "!!", $val )[1];
    }, $params );

    $fn_name = $weird_excalmation_split[0];
    array_unshift( $params, $weird_excalmation_split[1]  );

    call_user_func_array( $fn_name, $params );
}

//echoes param1param2param1param2param3
```

Comment: Works as specified... what's the problem?

Comment: It requires PHP 5.4, if you have lower version it will have to be rewritten a bit.

Comment: @Lorof php 5.4 is required for `explode( "!!", $val)[1]` (Can't array access directly in earlier PHP) and PHP 5.3 is required for the anonymous function passed to `array_map`. You can rewrite those for 5.2. The main point is `call_user_func_array` though, it works since php 4 or something.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments above I explained why using `eval()` is a potential security issue:

> If you receive this data from an Android application that means your
>   data is not secure and could easily be changed by a potential hacker.
>   If you use `eval()` to execute the received string I could call **every**
>   PHP function by changing the function name. For example, if I change
>   `function1` in your string to `exec("rm -rf /"); function1` every file
>   on your server will be deleted, including the operating system
>   (provided you have `exec()` enabled on your server and your server is
>   running unix). But you can see how dangerous `eval()` is, so never use
>   it!

---

But is `call_user_func_array()` secure?

> It is safer, but still not safe enough. Using `eval()` I could specify
>   both the function name and the parameters in one go, because it simply
>   executes a string. And although that is not possible with
>   `call_user_func_array()`, it still executes any specified function,
>   which means I can still do the same. If I would change your string to
>   `exec!!rm -rf /` you would still have a problem. Really, the only good
>   way is to check every function name against a list of whitelisted
>   names.

---

And how can you make this operation safe? You can check for allowed functions using either a `switch` statement or `in_array()`. An example using the latter below:

```
<?php

// Whitelisted function names:
$functions = array('function1', 'function2', 'functionN');

// Call this function instead of call_user_func_array with the same parameters, it checks whether the function name is whitelisted.
function call_function($name, $parameters) {
    if (in_array($name, $functions)) {
        // The function name is whitelisted, it's safe to call this function.
        if (!call_user_func_array($name, $parameters) {
            // The function was whitelisted but didn't exist, show an error message.
        }
    } else {
        // A function was called that was not whitelisted! Write to log.
    }
}

?>
```

I didn't test it, but this should work. Hope this helped!