# call function from variable

Tags: php

```
$scripts[0] = 'Say Hello';
$scripts[1] = 'Dont Say Hello';
$scripts[2] = 'Welcome';

$function_name = str_replace(' ', '_', $scripts[0]);   //Name of the function "Say_Hello"

echo $function_name('Jolly');   // Should echo "Hello Jolly"
```

I have a huge array with full of names which are associated with functions. In normal ways, if we are to call the function **Say_Hello()**, we do like this : **Say_Hello('Jolly')**. But in my case above, the name of the function is stored in a variable so how can I call it?

Thanks

Comment: Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php -

Comment: You can call it exactly like you've attempted to call it. What part of this isn't working? Did you actually try to write this yourself before posting this question?

Comment: *just a +1 for exactly what you have*: `$funcname();` works.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out PHP function [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) :

call_user_func — Call the callback given by the first parameter

example:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function increment(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a = 0;
call_user_func('increment', $a);
echo $a."\n";

call_user_func_array('increment', array(&$a)); // You can use this instead before PHP 5.3
echo $a."\n";
?>
```