# Variable's variable in function?

Tags: php

I need help with this:

```
$foo = array ('Projects', 'Clients');
```

And I need to run functions from pre-installed library

```
$bar->getProjects()->data
$bar->getClients()->data
```

etc. etc.

but I have it in the cycle. So I want something like

```
foreach($foo as $value)
  $return_value = $bar->get  >>>>$value<<<<  ()->data
```

How can this be done?

Comment: check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: look up [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

Comment: Ok I got it.. very useful but I managed to only echo it as a string with the variables .. how to actually run the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable):

```
foreach ($foo as $value) {
  $method = 'get' . $value;
  $return_value = $bar->$method()->data
}
```

or

```
foreach ($foo as $value)
  $return_value = $bar->{'get' . $value}()->data;
```

Comment: Man this is actually working! Simple and brilliant

Answer (score 1):

I'd use reflection, a well documented, no magic API:

```
<?php

$foo = array ('Projects', 'Clients');
$bar = new MyAwesomeClass();

var_dump(invokeMultipleGetters($bar, $foo));


// could also make this a method on MyAwesomeClass...
function invokeMultipleGetters($object, $propertyNames)
{
    $results = array();
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($object);

    foreach($propertyNames as $propertyName)
    {
        $method = $reflector->getMethod('get'.$propertyName);
        $result = $method->invoke($bar);
        array_push($results, $result)
    }

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: IMO this is the cleanest solution. It also allows you to get tons of information about the arguments that the method takes, if you need to start passing arguments in this as well.

Comment: @ColinMorelli The cleanest solution would be to not rely on dynamic method calls at all, but use interfaces instead.

Comment: @KingCrunch Of course - and I'm sure you and I have much more programming experience. But you can't teach programming concepts like "building to interfaces" to someone who is new with programming as they aren't likely to see the benefit. Given what was within the realm of possible answers for this question - this is probably one of the better solutions.

Comment: @KingCrunch: The question does not use interfaces but a rather random looking array of partial method names. No interfaces (or abstracts) mentioned there, so it would be weird and even more long winded if I had in my answer. Just going for the (imho) best tradeof between clean and pragmatic that could actually be used by the OP.

Comment: @Kris Yes, I know. I only commented ColinMorellis Statement about "the cleanest solution".

Answer (score 0):

There is a magic method for that: [__call](http://php.net/__call)

```
function __call($method, $params) {

     $var = substr($method, 3);

     if (strncasecmp($method, "get", 3)) {
         return $this->$var;
     }
     if (strncasecmp($method, "set", 3)) {
         $this->$var = $params[0];
     }
}
```

You can also take a look at [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)