# php function in array broken

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am trying to setup an array that pulls the filename and function name to run, but it not fully working.

The code is

```
$actionArray = array(
    'register' => array('Register.php', 'Register'),
);

if (!isset($_REQUEST['action']) || !isset($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']])) {
    echo '<br><br>index<br><br>';
    echo '<a href="?action=register">test</a>';
    exit;
}

require_once($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][0]);
return $actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][1];
```

Register.php has

```
function Register()
{
    echo 'register';

}


echo '<br>sdfdfsd<br>';
```

But it does not echo register and just sdfdfsd.

If I change the first lot of code from

```
return $actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][1];
```

to

```
return Register();
```

It works, any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: don't use `$_REQUEST`, use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead.

Comment: The code was from SMF forum software, I was just playing around with it, the only bit I changed was the echo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last line to:

```
return call_user_func($actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][1]);
```

This uses the [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function for more readable code and better portability. The following also should work (Only tested on PHP 5.4+)

```
return $actionArray[$_REQUEST['action']][1]();
```

It's almost the same as your code, but I'm actually invoking the function instead of returning the value of the array. Without the function invocation syntax `()` you're just asking PHP get to get the value of the variable (in this case, an array) and return it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find something usefull here:
[How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Call a function name stored in a string is what you want...