# Call static function from variable

Tags: php, class, static, class-method

I have the following setup:

```
class test {
     public static function something() {
          $somethingElseFunction = "somethingElse";

          // How can I call the method with the name saved in variable?
     }

     public static function somethingElse($a) {
          echo 'bla';
     }
}
```

How can I call the function using the variable? (the function name is in variable).
Also I need to do a function_exists() for it.

Tried this:

```
    if (function_exists(self::$somethingElseFunction ())) {
                if (!call_user_func(self::$somethingElseFunction , $a)) {

                }
            }
```

Didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Is not duplicate... is inside a class... if it was alone I could use call_user_func

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid static where you can ;)

Comment: Perfect... ty all... all answers work for calling... any help with the function_exists (can't use any sintax)?
@Anyone not when you really want it to be static ;).

Comment: You want to use `method_exists();`!

Comment: I cannot think if a single case I'd ever want to use a static :P

Comment: For example when it is a validator and you don't want to instantiate an object each time you validate something (you can say use singleton, but in some cases has more drawbacks than a static).

Comment: Worked for me for a static function call: $r=call_user_func("U::".$value,$input,$search);

Comment: @Anyone Don't avoid static. Using classes with static members and properties is a great way to break up a program into different portions dealing with different issues. You can hide most of the functions, constants, and variables so that they can be reused in other portions, even if you don't want or need to allocate class objects.

Comment: No, it really isn't a good way of dealing with different issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `PHP>=5.4` you can use just `self::` de-reference:

```
self::$somethingElseFunction();
```

-but in earlier versions that will cause error (because it wasn't allowed to use dynamic static methods de-reference). So then you can always use such things as [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) :

```
class test {
     public static function something() {
          $somethingElseFunction = "somethingElse";

         call_user_func_array(array(__CLASS__, $somethingElseFunction), array("bla"));
     }

     public static function somethingElse($a) {
          var_dump($a);
     }
}

test::something();
```

-this will work for `PHP>=5.0`

About [`function_exists()`](https://www.php.net/function_exists) call - it expects string as parameter, thus I recommend to use [`method_exists()`](https://www.php.net/method_exists) - because that function is intended to do the stuff:

```
 public static function something() {
     $somethingElseFunction = "somethingElse";
     if(method_exists(__CLASS__, $somethingElseFunction))
     {
        call_user_func_array(array(__CLASS__, $somethingElseFunction), array("bla"));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Need php 3.0 compatible :(. Still +1... and I'll accept this answer since is the most complete. Ty very much.

Comment: PHP version 3 has no concept of classes/objects whatsoever - good luck finding a solution

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following:

```
test::$somethingElseFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
$classname = 'somethingElse';
call_user_func('test::' . $classname, $params);
```

Comment: Can't be right. You're using a classname as a function name?