# Accessing a not declared method in a class with php

Tags: php

I am trying to understand this line of code:

```
$ret = $box->$command();
```

The method command is not defined in the class $box, and it is strange that there is a `$` before command. I just don't get it.

Comment: we can do it with __set(), __get(). check documentation.

Comment: This post explains it pretty good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable

Answer (score 4):

This executes the method with the name *stored in the* `$command` variable on the object stored in`$box`.

So, supposing the class of `$box` has a method called `foo`, then this would work:

```
$command = "foo";
$box->$command();
```

and would be equivalent to

```
$box->foo();
```

only that the former way is more flexible, as it allows you to dynamically call a function depending on the value of a variable. Beware to check the possible values of `$command` however, do take care that it isn't filled by user input somehow (that might allow malicious people to do unexpected things with the php code).

Answer (score 4):

```
$foo = 'bar';
$obj->$foo(); // calls the bar() method
```

You're looking at *variable method calling*.

Answer (score 2):

`$command` will be a string, the value of which is the name of a method in that class definition.