# What is the correct Syntax for calling a function in a string?

Tags: php, function

I keep getting an error that says function name must be in a string or it simply runs but doesn't print either string in the function. What am I missing?

```
<?php

$funName="{'$oneRun()'}";
echo "Hello You are running ".$funName."\n\n$";

function oneRun()
{ echo "Running Function One";return "one";}

function twoRun()
{ echo "Leave me alone, go bug Function One";return "two";}

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 3):

You mean [`callable`s](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) or [`variable function`s](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)?

```
$funName = 'oneRun'; // save only name

echo "Hello You are running " . $funName() . "\n\n$";
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks, I was making it too complex!

Comment: @Firehawk573 Welcome to SO. Take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Search similar [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable). Accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an echo in another echo, that couldn't work.

I guess something like :

```
<?php

$funName="{'$oneRun()'}";
echo "Hello You are running ";
oneRun();
echo "\n\n$";

function oneRun()
{ echo "Running Function One";return "one";}

function twoRun()
{ echo "Leave me alone, go bug Function One";return "two";}

?>
```

Would do the job ?

Answer (score 0):

I always use:

```
call_user_func($string_function_or_closure, ...);
call_user_func(array($object, 'Method'), ...);
call_user_func(array(StaticClass, 'Method'), ...);
```

or:

```
call_user_func_array($string_function_or_closure, array(...));
call_user_func_array(array($object, 'Method'), array(...));
call_user_func_array(array(StaticClass, 'Method'), array(...));
```

for string functions. It's a bit more explicit than:

```
$function();
```

and it also makes it better visible in your IDE.