# How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable with arguments

Tags: php

I found question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable). But I need to call function name with argument.
I need to be able to call a function, but the function name is stored in a variable, is this possible? e.g:

```
function foo ($argument)
{
  //code here
}

function bar ($argument)
{
  //code here
}

$functionName = "foo";
$functionName($argument);//Call here foo function with argument
// i need to call the function based on what is $functionName
```

Anyhelp would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow one doesn't expect such a question from a user with 4 golds. Your code already works

```
<?php

function foo ($argument)
{
  echo $argument;
}

function bar ($argument)
{
  //code here
}

$functionName = "foo";
$argument="Joke";
$functionName($argument); // works already, might as well have tried :)

?>
```

**Output**

> Joke

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/301418)**

Now on to a bit of theory, such functions are called **[Variable Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)**

> PHP supports the concept of variable functions. This means that if a variable name has parentheses appended to it, PHP will look for a function with the same name as whatever the variable evaluates to, and will attempt to execute it. Among other things, this can be used to implement callbacks, function tables, and so forth.

Comment: I need to call function like `$this->function_name` how can I do that?

Comment: That also works, with a little modification. `$this->$functionName();`

Comment: Sorry! to ask stupid question but It emergency for my project. anyway It work fine. Thanks

Comment: The question itself is not stupid, its a good question. But what's really not so cool about is is the fact that you have already written working code and instead of trying it you went ahead and asked others to run it :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a function dynamically with argument then you can try like this :

```
function foo ($argument)
{
  //code here
}

call_user_func('foo', "argument"); // php library funtion
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I need to call function like `$this->function_name` how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the php function [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

```
function foo($argument)
{
    echo $argument;
}

$functionName = "foo";
$argument = "bar";
call_user_func($functionName, $argument);
```

if you are in a class, you can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
//pass as first parameter an array with the object, in this case the class itself ($this) and the function name
call_user_func_array(array($this, $functionName), array($argument1, $argument2));
```

Comment: I need to call function like `$this->function_name` how can I do that?