# How to call php function with URL?

Tags: php, function, url, call

Hello Id like to know how to call the function I just written from URL?
Bellow are my php code.

```
<?php
require 'db.php';

function l1(){
    echo "Hello there!";
}

function l2(){
    echo "I have no Idea what Im doing!";
} 
function l3(){
    echo "I'm just a year 1 college student dont torture me sir!";
}


?>
```

I tried http://127.0.0.1/study/sf.php?function=l1 but it wont echo the written code.

Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: But seriously reconsider this. You don't want to give your visitors the possibility to randomly execute any PHP function somewhere in your code.

Comment: *What* do you not get?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could supply that parameter into calling your user defined function:

```
$func = $_GET['function'];
$func();
```

Might as well filter the ones you have defined thru [`get_defined_functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-functions.php)

```
function l1(){
    echo "Hello there!";
}

function l2(){
    echo "I have no Idea what Im doing!";
} 
function l3(){
    echo "I'm just a year 1 college student dont torture me sir!";
}

$functions = $arr = get_defined_functions()['user']; // defined functions

if(!empty($_GET['function']) && in_array($_GET['function'], $functions)) {
    $func = $_GET['function'];
    $func();
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/F0u6RH?function=l1)

Sidenote: `function_exists` can be also applied as well:

```
if(!empty($_GET['function']) && function_exists($_GET['function'])) {
    // invoke function
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer... You are also preventing the users from executing whatever function they want.  +1

Answer (score 1):

One option you can do if use if/elseifs like so:

```
if($_GET['function'] == 'l1')
{
    l1();
}
else if($_GET['function'] == 'l2')
{
    l2();
}
```

Or you could use a riskier approach and call the function name directly from the input.

```
$functionName = $_GET['function'];
$functionName();
```

Edit:
Or you could use a switch statement:

```
switch($_GET['function'])
{
    case 'l1':
        l1();
    break;
    case 'l2':
        l2();
    break;
    case 'l3':
        l3();
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is the approach that Im looking for but I dont know how to apply it.

Comment: I have added example code for a switch statement to my post.

Comment: Thank you Mex I really really appreciate it.