# Can I use variable functions with language constructs?

Tags: php, function, variables, language-construct

This question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable) kinda address the issue. In my case I would like to call a function like `empty()` or `is_int()`. For example:

```
<?php

    $foo = 'empty';
    $test = NULL;
    $foo($test);
```

This question is not a duplicate of:

[How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

My question addresses a native PHP function not a user made function.

Comment: It isn't a duplicate. My question addresses a native PHP function not a user made function.

Comment: afaik this is not really possible. Best way to do would be to put the PHP functions into your own methods and call it via call_user_func

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable function doesn't work with language constructs as you can read in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

> Variable functions **won't work with language constructs** such as echo, print, unset(), isset(), **empty()**, include, require and the like. Utilize wrapper functions to make use of any of these constructs as variable functions.