# Pass variables when calling method

Tags: php, function, methods

I am trying to pass variables when calling a method. I am trying to do something like this:

```
 $c->house_num.$id($name);
```

The name of the method is house_num_(number). I then want to pass another variable $name.

I am getting an error, what is the right way to do this? Thankyou

Comment: `$c->{'house_num'.$id}($name);`

Comment: you should be getting an undefined constant house_num notice here.

Comment: Why is the ID part of the method name, instead of another argument?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, it's parsed as `$c->house_num . $id($name)`, so it's looking for a property named `house_num`

Comment: I am trying to make it dynamic so that the id can be passed in, as there are multiple house_num_(number) methods

Comment: @Ryan My point is that you shouldn't have multiple `house_num_<number>` methods. You should have one `house_num($number, $name)` method.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. I questioned even myself after posting my comment about it. I should've deleted it when my little voice spoke to me.

Comment: @Ryan Any time you find yourself creating variables or methods in a numeric sequence, you should think about using an array instead.

Comment: I commented how to, but listen to @Barmar as far as... why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

```
$c->house_num($id,$name);
```

And then use somthing like

```
function house_num($id,$name){
switch($id){
 //call functions...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be use that :

```
$func = 'house_num_'.$id;

$c->$func($name);
```