# PHP - Calling methods whose names are stored in variables

Tags: php, oop, methods

Consider the class `abc`

```
class abc{
  public function xyz(){
     /*Some processing here*/
     return true;
  }
};
```

Suppose I don't know the name of the method directly, but have its name stored in variable, then how can I call the method?

Comment: Just do: `$obj->$method();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
class abc{
  public function xyz(){
     /*Some processing here*/
     return true;
  }
};

$method='xyz';  // Define your method name from database
$a= new abc();
$a->$method(); // call method
?>
```

Would you please refer above code ?

Comment: Ideally you also first check whether the method really exists via [method_exists($a, $method)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```
class abc{
  public function xyz(){
     echo "Called!";
  }
}

$obj = new abc();
$fun = "xyz";
call_user_func(array($obj, $fun));
```

Also answered here [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)