# Call a function from a stored string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I need is something that gets the variable and if the variable is the name of a function, the function will be called.
I am not trying to get a function from a module but from within the program itself

Example:

```
def foo():
    print("Foo")
callfunction = input("What function do you want to call? ")

callfunction() ## Not sure what to put here but but lets say callfunction is foo.
```

I don't want something like this because I have many functions:

```
if callfunction == "Foo"
    Foo()
else:
    print("No function with that name")
```

My question is something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable), but I ask for the Python syntax. I am using Python 3.5.1

Comment: Related: [How can I select a variable by (string) name?](/q/47496415/4518341)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this :

```
eval(input("What function do you want to call? ") + '()')
```

Comment: This allows the persons using it to execute arbitrary python code (just so long as whatever they do ends with a callable). For example they might just choose to erase all your files.

Comment: @KalkidanTadesseZewdieBeyene: At the first glance this might look like the easiest solution but it's a very very very dangerous solution. Read [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Answer (score 23):

Use a dict mapping names to functions.

```
call_dict = {
    'foo': foo,
    'bar': bar
}
call_dict[callfunction]()
```

Comment: how can i use this in class with self. call_dict[function_name]() ?

Comment: @drascom What do you mean? That code looks fine. Are the functions actually methods? Then it might get tricky.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite common in Python to use the command pattern. First move all of your functions into a class, and give them names which have a prefix that isn't used in the input. Then use `getattr()` to find the correct function and call it.

```
class Commands():
   def cmd_foo(self):
       print("Foo")

   def callFunction(self, name):
       fn = getattr(self, 'cmd_'+name, None)
       if fn is not None:
            fn()
```

This has a couple of advantages over Daniel's call_dict: you don't have to list the name of the functions a second time, and you don't have to list the callable functions a second time either.

The `'cmd_'` prefix is there to ensure you can have other methods in the class but still control exactly which ones are directly callable.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
import inspect
import your_module

list_of_functions = inspect.getmembers(your_module, inspect.isfunction)
```

Now `list_of_functions` is a list of tuples with the name of each function at position 0 and the function itself at position 1.