# how to convert string into object in python odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12, odoo-13, odoo-14

I have 2 methods
in method1:

```
def print_xls(self):
    record = self.env['sale.order'].search([('id','in',filtered_list)])
    data = {
        
        'model_recs':record
    }
    return self.env.ref('module_name.report_name').report_action(self, data=data)
```

in method 2:

```
def generate_xlsx_report(self, workbook, data, lines):
    h1 = workbook.add_format({'font_size': 16, 'align': 'center', 'align':'center','valign':'vcenter', 'bold': True,'underline':True})
    sheet = workbook.add_worksheet('sale dept')
    sheet.merge_range(1, 0, 3, 17,"Sale Report",h1)
    print(data['model_recs'])
```

I am getting data['model_recs'] = 'sale.order(1,2,3)'

My question is how to convert the string model 'sale.order(1,2,3)' into Model/object sale.order(1,2,3), so the i can get it's field data like sale.order[0].some_field in second method.

Comment: There is something missing here. You flll `data` in the first part, but don't use it in the second. Can you add that please?

Comment: That should be normal recordsets (objects), but the string representation is like you're saying. Did you try to loop on them?

Comment: @CZoellner cannot loop over string 'sale.order(1,2,3)'. that's why I want to convert that string into record set/model.

Comment: okay, that's weird.

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval("sale.order(1,2,3)")

```py
>>> eval("str(1)")
'1'
>>> eval("type(str(1))")
<class 'str'>

>>> class x:
...     def gg(self, x, y, z):
...             print(x, y, z)
... 
>>> eval('x().gg(1,2,3)')
1 2 3
```

From here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42227653/7035448

While it is very powerful method it is also worthwhile to note problems with eval [eval_problems](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)