# How can I invoke php function from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, function, xampp

I have a system for mailing. I want to call the required function from the database, where there is the name for it. eg. I have a mail type "Attendance", I want to call the mail function attendance()(It has the content for monthly attendance to be sent to all employees), from the database as I have many other functions also.

Comment: If I get you right you want to call a function where the string `Attendance` is the function name which you get from database. So could be a possible duplicate of [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: As a note, executing arbitrary code stored in a database is extremely risky and is best avoided unless you have exhausted all other options. It's better to have the code in your regular PHP code-base, and just the name of a function to execute in the table, referencing it that way instead.

Comment: I have found the solution with hit and trial. I stored the function name with parameters(like, "a(a,b,c)") and then called it from  my php file as, echo $row['a_name'];