# Post to php variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In php, I want to pass a php variable using the jquery.post method.

The first figure shows the code that post the variable
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH5El.png)

The second figure shows to read the posted variable.[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n0cI.png)

php variable contains some statements, but output will print the variable names like "$rxss", "$sxss".

The post method seems to be writing the data part incorrectly, so please let me know how to write it.

add

i already tested

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post("scanner/getStatus.php", {testId:' . "$testId" . ',chkCnt:' . "$chkCount" . ',rxss:' . "$rxss" . ',sxss:' . "$sxss" . ',sqli:' . "$sqli" . ',basqli:' . "$basqli" . ',autoc:' . "$autoc" . ',idor:' . "$idor" . ',dirlist:' . "$dirlist" . ',bannerdis:' . "$bannerdis" . ',sslcert:' . "$sslcert" . ',unredir:' . "$unredir" . ',clamav:' . "$clamav" . '}, function(data){$("#status").html(data)});
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$.post("scanner/getStatus.php", {testId:' . "$testId" . ',chkCnt:' . "$chkCount" . ',rxss:' . "$rxss" . ',sxss:' . "$sxss" . ',sqli:' . "$sqli" . ',basqli:' . "$basqli" . ',autoc:' . "$autoc" . ',idor:' . "$idor" . ',dirlist:' . "$dirlist" . ',bannerdis:' . "$bannerdis" . ',sslcert:' . "$sslcert" . ',unredir:' . "$unredir" . ',clamav:' . "$clamav" . '}, function(data){$("#status").html(data)});
}, 500); ......
```

-

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.post("scanner/getStatus.php", {testId:' . "$testId" . ',chkCnt:' . "$chkCount" . ',rxss:"" + $rxss + "",sxss:"" + $sxss + "",sqli:""+ $sqli + "",basqli:"" + $basqli + "",autoc:"" + $autoc + "",idor:"" + $idor + "",dirlist:"" + $dirlist + "",bannerdis:"" + $bannerdis + "",sslcert:"" + $sslcert + "",unredir:"" + $unredir + "",clamav:"" + $clamav + ""}, function(data){$("#status").html(data)});
  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
$.post("scanner/getStatus.php", {testId:' . "$testId" . ',chkCnt:' . "$chkCount" . ',rxss:"" + $rxss + "",sxss:"" + $sxss + "",sqli:""+ $sqli + "",basqli:"" + $basqli + "",autoc:"" + $autoc + "",idor:"" + $idor + "",dirlist:"" + $dirlist + "",bannerdis:"" + $bannerdis + "",sslcert:"" + $sslcert + "",unredir:"" + $unredir + "",clamav:"" + $clamav + ""}, function(data){$("#status").html(data)});
}, 500); ......
```

but when these test not showing getStatus.php and apache log haven't error

Comment: because you use simple quote to echo your html, so it print it literally you have do the same that you use for $testId (and you don't need to use double quote when you concatene for variable in php)

Comment: Add your code as code to the question. **Do not** post code as screenshots/images.

Answer (score -2):

You can you this `$("$yourvariable")`
Also take a look at this [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Please extend your answer to contain more than just links. Also, `eval` is usually evil.