# Is there a __call() magic method alternative in procedural PHP?

Tags: php, call, fallback, procedural

Is there any alternative for the __call() magic method in procedural PHP? I want to provide a fallback for undefined functions.

My usage case specifically is that I'm using a famous CMS built in procedural, and I want to use regular functions on the theme files and call those functions from Classes from behind the scenes, so I need some kind of fallback for undefined functions.

Comment: Register an error handler and deal with it there.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php  or test it ahead of time with `function_exists()`

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using PHP 7, you could wrap your calls to undefined functions in a `try {…} catch (Error $e) {…}` block and handle the fallback from there. [[1]](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)

Pre-PHP7, I can’t think of something that doesn’t involve wrapping all function calls or using `function_exists`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you were searching for might be: [$functionName()](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) or [call_user_func($functionName)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) see: [How to call PHP function from string stored in a Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-php-function-from-string-stored-in-a-variable) (So all credit goes to: [user knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl)

(Just saw your question when googling for something similar. So I thought I put the answer here for everyone who searches for the same thing).