# How to dynamically set an object property value?

Tags: php

I have a customer object data:

```
App\Entity\Customer {#661
    -id: 100003
    -manufacturer: "TEST A"
    -description: "This is a description"
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

From an array which consist of column name I need to reset the object value.

From the array, with a loop:

```
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'manufacturer') {
        $customer->setManufacturer($value);
    }

    if ($key === 'description') {
        $customer->setDescription($value);
    }
   ... and so on...
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically set the object without making multiple if condition.

I have tried following:

```
$label = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
$tyre->{$label} = $value;
```

But it is not updating the object instead adding

[image: Appended label]

Comment: you’re trying to call a method, but are instead setting a property. Calling a method works the same way, except with parentheses. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005857/how-to-call-a-function-from-a-string-stored-in-a-variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but you should *call* the (dynamically named) method, not assign to it:

```
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    $label = 'set' . ucfirst($key);
    $customer->{$label}($value); // <-- call it!
}
```

Comment: To go further, you could also check the existence of the method before calling her (method_exists).

Comment: Thanks. It works.

`if (method_exists($record, $label)) {
    $customer->{$label}($value);
}`