# "Build" class call from database values

Tags: php, database

I got a database table that has a class-name, method and parameters saved in it:

```
class | method | parameters
---------------------------
User  | logIn  | para1
```

I now need to call it in my script. I have "User" saved in `$class`, "logIn" saved in `$method` and "para1" saved in `$para`:

```
$class->$method($para);
```

Is this anyhow possible?

Comment: Did you try `$class->{$method}($para);`? Your original way to do it would still work as well...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic class method invocation in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251485/dynamic-class-method-invocation-in-php)

Comment: Have you instantiated an instance of the `User` class and saved _that_ into `$class` instead of just the string "User"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this solved OP's problem, and as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251485/dynamic-class-method-invocation-in-php) (awaiting duplicate closure for this problem) and PHP's standard methodology of [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), you can use:

```
$class->{$method}($para);
```

However `$class->$method($para);` should also work as well.