# Laravel - using array_walk_recursive() in a Laravel Class

Tags: php, laravel, methods, callback, static-methods

I'm bringing a standard php class into Laravel.

The problem I'm having is calling the printable function using array_walk_recursive().

This the snippet of code from my class:

```
public static function print_r($response)
{
    // Format response (for testing)

    if (is_object($response)) $response = (array)$response;
    if (!is_array($response) && $response) $response = json_decode($response, true);
    if (is_array($response))
    {
        array_walk_recursive($response, "printable");
        echo "<pre>" . print_r($response, true) . "</pre>";
    }
}

private static function printable(&$v, $k)
{
    // Format response (for testing)

    if (!is_array($v))
    {
        if (is_bool($v))
        {
            if ($v) $v = "true"; else $v = "false";
        }
        else if (is_null($v))
        {
            $v = "null";
        }
        else
        {
            $v = trim(str_replace("<", "&lt;", str_replace(">", "&gt;", $v)));
        }
    }
}
```

The error:

"array_walk_recursive() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'printable' not found or invalid function name"

So it seems like it's just not finding the printable function. What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use class methods as callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28954168/how-to-use-class-methods-as-callbacks)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the object. In this case it will be `self`:

```
array_walk_recursive($response, 'self::printable');
```

Comment: I'm afraid that gives the error "Undefined variable: this"

Comment: Oh yeah, you're using static methods. Please try updated code.

Comment: Thank you, It works for me.
`private function addSpan(&$value, $key)
    {
        $value = "<span>{$value}</span>";
    }

array_walk($replace, 'self::addSpan');`