# Undefined variable: purify and method name must be a string while using HTML purifier

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

Line with error:

```
$msg = $purifier->$purify($result['Message']);
```

Error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: purify in /storage/ssd5/777/1537777/public_html/inc/ticketBody.php on line 41
```

and

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Method name must be a string in /storage/ssd5/777/1537777/public_html/inc/ticketBody.php:41 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd5/777/1537777/public_html/inc/ticketBody.php on line 41
```

Config:

```
require_once '../HTMLPurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'div, *[style|class]');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
```

I don't understand what is the issue...

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

`$purifier->purify($result['Message']);`

as referenced in the [docs](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs), not

```
$purifier->$purify($result['Message']);
```

You do not have a `$purify` variable declared, hence the error.

P.S: The initial syntax is valid because you might want to dynamic call methods, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251485/dynamic-class-method-invocation-in-php)

Comment: Ohhh... my bad, thanks alot, I need to wait 11 mins before accepting this